# How to create Azure Databricks Job cluster to save some costing compared to Standard cluster?

Tags: azure-databricks, cost-management

I have a few pipeline jobs on Azure Databricks that run ETL solutions using standard or high concurency clusters.

I've noticed on azure costings page that job cluster is a cheaper option that should do the same thing. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/calculator/

All Purpose - Standard_DS3_v2

```
0.75DBU
×
£0.292Per DBU per hour
×
=
£0.22
```

Job Cluster - Standard_DS3_v2

```
0.75DBU
×
£0.109Per DBU per hour
×
=
£0.08
```

I have configured job cluster by creating a new job and selecting new job cluster as per tutorial below: https://docs.databricks.com/jobs.html#create-a-job

The job was successfull and ran for couple days. However, the cost did not really go down. Have I missed anything?

Cluster Config

```
{
    "autoscale": {
        "min_workers": 2,
        "max_workers": 24
    },
    "cluster_name": "",
    "spark_version": "9.1.x-scala2.12",
    "spark_conf": {
        "spark.databricks.delta.preview.enabled": "true",
        "spark.scheduler.mode": "FAIR",
        "spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode": "dynamic",
        "spark.databricks.service.server.enabled": "true",
        "spark.databricks.repl.allowedLanguages": "sql,python,r",
        "avro.mapred.ignore.inputs.without.extension": "true",
        "spark.databricks.cluster.profile": "serverless",
        "spark.databricks.service.port": "8787"
    },
    "azure_attributes": {
        "first_on_demand": 1,
        "availability": "ON_DEMAND_AZURE",
        "spot_bid_max_price": -1
    },
    "node_type_id": "Standard_DS3_v2",
    "ssh_public_keys": [],
    "custom_tags": {},
    "spark_env_vars": {
        "PYSPARK_PYTHON": "/databricks/python3/bin/python3"
    },
    "enable_elastic_disk": true,
    "cluster_source": "JOB",
    "init_scripts": []
}
```

Comment: show the configuration that you've used. Job cost won't got down if you point it to existing cluster

Comment: is your job streaming? streaming doesn't work well yet with autoscaling. Also, why do you need serverless profile?

Comment: @AlexOtt - No, it is batch job running basic etl pipelines. I believe serverless was just a default setting at a time all-purpose cluster was created and config copied over to job cluster.

Comment: Jobs will decrease only DBU cost. You can spare on the hardware cost by setting availability attribute set to SPOT_AZURE or Spot with fallback